CORS blocked in Google Apps Script
I am attempting to create an app in Apps Script. Right now I am just attempting to get a drop down to populate correctly with data from a google sheet.
This is my code.gs for the backend:
// Serve the HTML frontend (index.html)
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
    .setTitle('Financial Dashboard');
}

// Fetch unique FINMGR values from the Mgmt Report Data workbook
function getFinMgrData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("WORKBOOk-ID"); // Google Sheet workbook ID
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Adjust to the correct sheet name if necessary
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // Get all data from the sheet

  // Extract unique FINMGR values (assuming FINMGR is in column A)
  const finMgr = [...new Set(data.map(row => row[0]))]; // Column A for FINMGR

  return { finMgr }; // Return an object containing the FINMGR data
}

// API endpoint to fetch FINMGR data (called from the frontend)
function getDropdownOptions() {
  const dropdownData = getFinMgrData(); // Fetch the FINMGR data
  
  // Return the data as a JSON response
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(dropdownData))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

This is my index.html frontend:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Financial Dashboard</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Financial Dashboard</h1>

    <!-- Dropdown Filters -->
    <select id="finMgr">
      <option value="">Select FINMGR</option>
    </select>

    <script>
      // Fetch dropdown data from the backend (get FINMGR data)
      async function fetchDropdownData() {
        try {
          const response = await fetch('APP-URL');
          const dropdownData = await response.json();

          // Populate the FINMGR dropdown with the data
          populateDropdown("finMgr", dropdownData.finMgr);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching dropdown data:", error);
        }
      }

      // Helper function to populate a dropdown
      function populateDropdown(elementId, options) {
        const dropdown = document.getElementById(elementId);
        options.forEach(option => {
          const opt = document.createElement("option");
          opt.value = option;
          opt.textContent = option;
          dropdown.appendChild(opt);
        });
      }

      // Initialize page by fetching dropdown data
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        fetchDropdownData();  // Fetch FINMGR data to populate the dropdown
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

I currently receive these errors:

Access to fetch at 'APP-URL' from origin 'https://n-ejhl2wga3ensngpnpaar2cawz7ncopfyfnvdlty-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.


Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED


Error fetching dropdown data: TypeError: Failed to fetch
at fetchDropdownData (userCodeAppPanel:5:34)
at HTMLDocument. (userCodeAppPanel:28:9)

I have made several CORS header attempts on my own and failed. I am looking for some help. I have verified my WORKBOOK-ID, and my APP-URL. My deployment is access for all, and google sheet access open as well. I am expecting my FINMGR dropdown to populate with the FINMGR list and it is not.

Json will trigger cors. Use simple requests. See linked duplicate
